# Check if a specific locale is enabled in bash

Tags: bash, locale

My script needs to run a program with a specific locale to work correctly, so I want it to check whether that locale is available. I've used this hack for now, but I think there's a better way to do this.

```
grep ^ja_JP /etc/locale.gen &>/dev/null || echo >&2 "enable any of the japanese locales first"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`man locale` would tell you that `locale -a` would list all available locales.

Instead say:

```
locale -a | grep -q ^ja_JP || echo "enable any of the japanese locales first"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, locale -a is inadequate to validate a configuration option, because it would reject valid cases.  For example, I can use "en_CA.utf8" and "en_CA.UTF-8" to the same effect but the latter fails because locale -a lists the former.  This is particularly undesirable when writing code that's going to be deployed across diverse environments, yet as yet I can find no other way to validate a configuration choice at all.

Answer (score 4):

`locale -a` should list all the available locales:

```
if locale -a | grep ^ja_JP ; then
    # locale installed...
else
    # locale not installed...
fi
```